# Displaying content at correct scale in UIWebView on iPad

Tags: ipad, uiwebview, nsstring

I have a UIWebView set to scale to fit in an iPad app that gets its content from and NSString.

If I turn off scale to fit the text is bigger, although would like it to be much bigger, but I lose the zooming feature.

If I set scale to fit on the text is very small as it is obviously scaling the lot to fit the page...and I get zooming back.

How do I get it to allow me to zoom but also decide how large or how small I want the font to be upon first displaying the content?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Put this in the CSS of your HTML (or your local .css file), and when loaded on an iPad, the font will be twice the size of the iPhone. I just used it in a project and it worked like a charm.

```
@media all and (min-device-width: 481px) and (max-device-width: 1024px) {
        body { font-size: 200%; }   
    }
```

You can also do media queries for portrait / landscape and so on.

Answer (score 0):

```
  NSString *webViewContent = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"<html> \n"
                                "<head> \n"
                                "<style type=\"text/css\"> \n"
                                "body {font-family: \"%@\"; font-size: %@;}\n"
                                "</style> \n"
                                "</head> \n"
                                "<body>%@</body> \n"
                                "</html>", @"helvetica", [NSNumber numberWithInt:kFieldFontSize], content];
//kFieldFontSize = 'specify your font size'

[yourWebVIew loadHTMLString:webViewContent baseURL:nil];
```

use the above method to change the font.